# Android XML layer-list: How to position the top layer

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

I have this XML drawable - tab_background_unselected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/background_grey" />            
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

which creates this shape:

[image: background rectangle]

and this arrow shape xml drawable - tab_selected_arrow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/background_dark_green" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

which creates this shape:

[image: top layer triangle]

I'm using this drawable XML (instead of PNG file) in order to create a layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected">
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_arrow">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

but I want the final image to look like this:

[image: final image]

I don't know how to set the gravity of the arrow (the second item and the top layer) to center|bottom...
I've tried using `bitmap` tag but it only accepts image files.

I need this to be a XML drawable because

1. I need it to be inside a drawable selector
2. I don't want to make it a PNG and create different file for each screen resolution

Answer (score 9):

Use an inner `Bitmap` drawable inside the `item`, and set `gravity` for it:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected">
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_selected_arrow" />
</item>
```

Comment: Asaf said he tried with Bitmap drawables, and he's correct: they don't allow XML drawables (I've just corrected the question and now the "bitmap" tag in "I've tried using..." appears)

Comment: AFAIK no way, there is a bug in  API 21-22, no vectros in bitmap element here :(

Comment: Should be more highlighted:
this answer only works when "tab_selected_arrow" is a .png!!!